# PHP 35: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, curl

cURL stopped working. I started to get this error (it used work fine till few hours ago).

I am using cURL extension for PHP. I found some solution for curl command line, but unfortunately i do not understand them :/ and I do not know how to move them to PHP cURl flags.

cURL conf:

```
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pln.bitcurex.com/data/ticker.json");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);

if(substr($url, 0, 5)=='https') curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

if($this->ciastko)
{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->ciastko);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->ciastko);
}

if($this->post)
{
    if( is_array($this->post) && count($this->post) > 0 )
    {
        $postdata = http_build_query($this->post,'','&');
    }
    elseif( is_string($this->post) )
    {
        $postdata = $this->post;
    }
    else $postdata = '';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
}

$wynik=curl_exec($curl);
```

error:

35: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: same issue https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/209

Answer (score 12):

I just change from

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

to

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);

Answer (score 11):

I know it's a bit outdated problem, but I've got a solution for others:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');
```

Comment: Can you please explain what these setting do and how it is related to curl error message asked about in the question?

Comment: This is not working, and I am having the same issue... This seems to be happening on older Centos 5 based servers, with older OpenSSL 0.9.8

Comment: Due to the POODLE vulnerability many sites are now disabling SSL 3.0. You should switch to TLS, which would look like this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1)

Answer (score 0):

**Input values :**

```
$params = Array
    (
        "username" => "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "password" => "XXXXXX"
    );

$path ='https://www.XXXXXXXX.com/xx/xxx/format/json/';
```

**Function:**

```
function curlpost($parameters, $path){
     $apiUrl = $path;
     $curl_handle = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1024);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
     $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);

     $content = curl_exec( $curl_handle );
     $err     = curl_errno( $curl_handle );
     $errmsg  = curl_error( $curl_handle );
     $header  = curl_getinfo( $curl_handle );
     curl_close( $curl_handle );

     $header['errno']   = $err;
     $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
     $header['content'] = $content;
    curl_close($curl_handle);
     return $header;
 }
```