# My paypal stop accepting payment and giving me error

Tags: php, ssl, paypal

I am Using `PHP-PayPal-IPN` and it was working fine before last 5 days since last 2 years. But when i got my last payment it stuck and start giving me error.. any idea?

My error which i get in error file is

```
[16-Oct-2014 12:45:42 UTC] cURL error: [35] error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Here is php file which giving this error

```
<?php

class IpnListener {

    public $use_curl = true;     

    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     

    public $follow_location = false;     

    public $use_ssl = true;      

    public $use_sandbox = false; 

    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
                    dirname(__FILE__)."/api_cert_chain.crt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 35: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3\_READ\_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568539/php-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-handshake-failur)

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error, and it started yesterday.

Comment: I am trying to change some code and trying to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');` but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Jeremy we got it it works see answer of Deepak

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this i guess it will work 99%

Change this to

```
    if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    }
```

To this

```
    if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');
    } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    }
```

Comment: This fixed it for me too - can anyone explain what caused this error to start with? What changed with cURL or Paypal?

Comment: PayPal disabled SSLv3 last week in response to the ShellShock vulnerability: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Forward/PayPal-Response-to-SSL-3-0-Vulnerability-aka-POODLE/ba-p/891829

Comment: The updated merchant guid reccomends not using SSLv3 and TLSv1 instead. likeso curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);

Comment: YES paypal changed SSL version even the `else {}` function is useless but its better to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must change line 32

```
public $force_ssl_v3 = true;
```

to

```
public $force_ssl_v3 = false;
```