# Clash Of Clan API | error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl

My Severs disable with SSLv3 due to "Poodle Vulnerability".

I need to use the CURL to connect with Clash of Clan API. But I am getting error that is: `"error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"`

I tried using:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It's working fine on my local system but not on the sever.

**Code**

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/%23LRQ0PJL9');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
?>
```

**Service Version :**

PHP :

```
v5.4.42
```

OpenSSL Details :

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

CURL Details :

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
niralvwn@md-17 [/etc]# curl --v
curl: option --v: is ambiguous
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
niralvwn@md-17 [/etc]# curl -version
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
niralvwn@md-17 [/etc]# curl -V
curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 35: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3\_READ\_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568539/php-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-handshake-failur)

Comment: I tried from above thread, Not working for me

Comment: Awesome.. I didn't know they had API that works out like WoW.. Looking forward for creating my clan web stats.

Comment: Everything, I did on my localhost but I can't able to make live. Looking for solution !!

Comment: Have you added the IP address of your server on your CoC API Key `Allowed IP Address` property?

Comment: Yes, I Added... Thing is is not connecting to coc server.If connected means it will get data like 'Not Authentication' or Other thing like that.

Comment: Anyway, I did all my authentication and added IP on COC

Comment: Post your full code without api key..

Comment: Update My Question with code

Comment: Your code works fine on my part as well. I am using cURL (7.35.0) and PHP (5.5.9). I don't think the problem lies in your code but on your server instead.

Comment: Can, I know you OpenSSL version. I will try to contact my Service Provider

Comment: The site requites [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). My guess is that the (unknown) version of your curl library is too old and does not has SNI support yet. Fiddling with certificate validation will not help and is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: I've also tried with my own VPS which also works perfectly. I don't think its related with openssl, I just had to install `php5-curl` and without `libcurl4-openssl-dev` on my server just now. Anyway the versions for both my local and vps are `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16`.

Comment: Okay, Updated the question with service version

Comment: Great choz !! Thanks

Comment: FYI, our curls a bit different. It returned `Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp`. And `Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP`

Comment: Choz, I raised ticket on service provider website . Waiting for their reply on mean time.

Comment: Steffen, Update my version on question. You can check on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my hosting problem.
Upgrading Open SSL fixes the issue.

Thanks a lot for all

Answer (score 0):

Where you setup you API key you're also entering the IP from which their API allows requests. Maybe you added your own IP but not your server IP in that list?

https://developer.clashofclans.com