# Laravel send API request using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I am trying to send a `GET` request using GuzzleHttp in Laravel.

```php
try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
        [
            [
                'curl' => array(
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 2,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => 1,
                    CURLAUTH_BASIC => 1
                )
            ], ['verify' => false]
        ]
    );

    $res = $client->get('https://10.10.0.254:1025/restconf/data/ietf-system:system-state?content=all',
        [
            'auth' => ['restconf-api', 'rest.b']
        ]
    );
    var_dump($res);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

I get the following error.

> cURL error 35: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

As you see in my code I already disabled SSL verification, but still, I get this error. When I tried using postman first I get SSL error then when I disabled SSL verification it is working fine without any problem. How can I disable SSL verification?

[image: image of postman]

Comment: Maybe it's a bit outdated problem. Would you please try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568539/php-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-handshake-failur

Comment: _“as you see in my code I already disabled ssl verification”_ - are you sure `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 2` isn’t overwriting what you are trying to do with `'verify' => false` here …?

Comment: @04FS I tried with all choices , I removed verify=>false without success

Comment: Sounds like your API HTTPS part might be using outdated cipher suites, https://serverfault.com/questions/889631/curl-fails-to-retrieve-https-content-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-byte

Comment: @04FS yes you are right , but how can I solve this problem I already added this to my code                                                                                                                                     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256');  but I had this problem error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available

Comment: @04FS in the other hand why when I disabled SSL Certificate Verification option it working without problem

Comment: What now? You said before that you _did_ try to disable it, and that didn’t work, and gave you the same error.

Comment: I mean in postman program when I disabled ssl verification option it working , but not working from my php code